# Hide a Personal Secret in SharePoint

Tags: office365, sharepoint-online

I am a user that is logged into SharePoint Online. I have a secret number. My secret number is **42** and I want to save this number somewhere safe where no one else but me can see it.

I have access to any client side scripting and can easily save content in user profile properties, but this would not be a secret place to store such sensitive information. It would just be out of sight, but that is not enough for my scenario. It needs to be truly secret or encrypted.

Any ideas what I can do in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Encrypt it, or create a truecrypt or similar volume and put it there, then upload the file.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion how? If it's encrypted, how can he user retrieve his number 42? He needs it? If he is going to un-encrypt it, how can we do this safely on the clientside. If we need to keep a secret unencryption key on the client, then the next question is just where do we keep that new secret then?